# Change section opacity onclick?

Tags: javascript, html, css, onclick, opacity

I'm trying to change the opacity of a  with javascript when a div is clicked.

Here is my html:

```
<section id="section2">
<img onclick="one()" class=img src="1.png" />
</section>
<section id="6-1">
    Hello World
</section>
```

And my javascript:

```
function one() {
    document.getElementById('6-1').style.opacity = '1';
    document.getElementById('section2').style.opacity = '0';
}
```

For some reason, its not working

Thanks!

Comment: What browser are you testing in?

Comment: And what does your css look like?

Comment: ID's starting with numbers are invalid, other than that it works just fine -> [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/eYvDQ/1/)

Comment: When using opacity, you should try to look for cross-browser compatibility. So, IE 9+ and most modern browsers use opacity=1, IE8- uses filter='alpha(opacity=100)', others use -moz-opacity=1 and -khtml-opacity=1.

Answer (score 2):

Try to set the value without the ' ', like this:

`document.getElementById("section2").style.opacity = 1;`

It worked for me just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Like ModernDesigner said, enquote your attributes and change your ids to not start with numbers, but other than that, I still couldn't figure out your problem. But for now you can use jQuery to make it work.

Here's a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Q2NMZ/2/) that toggles it every time you click it, so hope this helps

It kept saying the function wasn't defined, so maybe you had some incorrect syntax or something. For now though i used jQuery's `.click()` function instead of `onClick=` because it wasn't working.